# preg replace remove the same repeated non-word character

Tags: char, preg-replace, character

I want to remove the same repeated non-word character.

My code looks like this:

```
<?php
$name = 'Malines - Blockbuster (prod. Malines) ***** (((((( &%^$';
echo preg_replace('/[^\pL\pN\s]{2,}/u', '', $name);
?>
```

`Malines - Blockbuster (prod. Malines) ***** (((((( &%^$` should be `Malines - Blockbuster (prod. Malines) &%^$`

Only repeated non-word character should be removed. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same idea than Arlaud Agbe Pierre (that is the way to do it), the pattern can be shorten using the Xan character class. `\p{Xan}` is the union of `\p{L}` and `\p{N}`. `\P{Xan}` (with an uppercase "p") is the negation of this class (i.e. *all that is not a letter or a number*).

```
$str = 'Malines - Blockbuster (prod. Malines) ààà ***** (((((( &%^$';

echo preg_replace('~(\P{Xan})\1+~u', '$1', $str);
```

Note: in this pattern, consecutive white characters are removed too.

an other way:

```
echo preg_replace('~(\P{Xan})\K\1+~u', '', $str);
```

where `\K` resets the begining of the match from the match result. *(note that you can however define capturing groups before that you can use after)*

Answer (score 2):

You must use back-reference to say that the second character is the same as the one before :

```
/([^\pL\pN\s])\1+/u
```

Comment: I tried this and this replaces 'Malines - Blockbuster (prod. Malines) ***** (((((( &%^$' to 'Malines - Blockbuster (prod. Malines) * &%^$' - removes all "(" but should leave one.

Comment: preg_replace('/([^\pL\pN\s])\1+/u', '\1', $name);